# Resolution for Import Error when trying to import 'Requests'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests, importerror

I am currently having trouble using requests. I use the import requests command yet I get the import error that says `no module named 'requests'`.

To install it I first installed SetupTools, then pip and finally used the `pip install requests` command. This didn't work so I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling (with `pip3` and `pip3.5` commands) yet it still doesn't work.

I am using python 3.5 which is installed directly to my `c:\` drive.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `where.exe python` and `where.exe pip`?

Comment: always add in question full error message - we can't read in your mind.

Comment: Thanks Nick, based on that I noticed they were in different directories (python in `c:` and pip in `c:\Scripts`) so I tried using the install options in the pip command to install direct to `c:` but I got this error after it downloaded:
    `Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by just reinstalling `requests` to the `c:` drive (which didn't fully solve it) and then just moving the `requests` folder to `c:\Lib` which now works fine and allows me to import it properly.